# Unit tests in VS2010 (solution in release mode)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to run my unit tests (Test->Debug->Tests in current solution) in VS 2010.
The solution is built in Release mode. When I try to do that, VS is crashing.

Do you have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Is it crashing in your code or somewhere else? Does MSTEST crash from the command line run of the tests too?

Comment: It crashed immediately after trying to start UT. "Vs is shutting down..."

Comment: didn't check. I wonder if I could debug the UT if they are built in Release mode

Comment: Try building in debug mode, switching to release mode, and then running the tests.  We have a few tests that misbehave when run in release w/o a debug build first.  I haven't gone hunting for the reason - I just know what the workaround for my scenario is.  Hopefully this will be a bandaid solution for you as well.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Ive tried your workaround - unfortunately with no results.

Comment: Is your code coverage correctly configured for the output location of the release build? (Test - Edit Test Settings - Data and Diagnostics - Code Coverage - Configure)

Comment: @Peter, I believe you work with Ultimate version - these options are not available in Professional edition that I work with.

Comment: I'm running Premium, so yeah, that may not be there in Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem lies with the test code. Test code is crashing and bringing down the VS IDE too.

See while debugging, the tests are run in-proc and therefore because of any exception in test code the VS would crash too.

I would suggest that you set the "Break on Common language runtime exceptions" (Goto Debug -> Exceptions menu), and then debug the tests. That way you could hunt the exception in your test code.